# Nextjs dynamic routes in Amplify

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I have the following directory structure in my Nextjs app:

pages/post/[id]/index.js

I am trying to configure Amplify to correctly route this URL:

mydomain.com/post/123

I have the following rewrite configured:

```
{
    "source": "/post/<*>",
    "target": "/post/[id]/index.html",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
},
```

But it isn't working. What is the correct format for the Amplify rewrite when the directory is a dynamic route?

My routes do work when running locally. I can't get it configured in Amplify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have `mydomain.com/post/123` work, then your directory needs to match this route:

```
pages
 |    
 +-- post
 |  |  
 |  \-- [id].js
```

With your directory structure, the dynamic route doesn't know which file to load since `index.js` is resolved for a folder route such as `/posts`

Creating a file with the square braces will catch your `/123` route as mentioned in the next.js docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

The current rewrite rule you have should work for this structure where you do something like this as the rule:

```
{
    "source": "/post/<*>",
    "target": "/post/[id].html",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
}
```

Comment: This is a lifesaver, though I found I needed to structure this slightly differently:   

```
pages
|
+--post
| |
| \-- index.js  <- this just re-exports [id].js
| \-- [id].js
```   

with   

```
{
    "source": "/post/<*>",
    "target": "/post/,
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
{
    "source": "/legal/<*>",
    "target": "/legal/[pid]/index.html",
    "status": "404-200",
    "condition": null
}
```

| Source address | Target address | Type | Country code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /legal/<*> | /legal/[pid]/index.html | 404 (Rewrite) | - |

Comment: Do we have to do this for all the SSR routes?

Comment: @Youzef yes, all of the dynamic routes you cant/dont want to pre-generate.